# Dual boot Ubuntu and Windows 8 on a SSD+HDD ultrabook

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8, ssd

I have this configuration on an Asus VivoBook:

[image]

Disk 0 is a 1 TB HDD disk while Disk 2 is a 24 GB SSD. I would like to keep the existing windows 8 installation and add Ubuntu in dual boot.

I will be using Ubuntu as my preferred system but I'm not sure what is the best configuration in order to optimize the use of the SSD disk. Notice that this particular model does not use Intel Smart Response Technology. I think that it uses the SSD as some kind of cache, but I'm not sure about this and I don't want to mess up the entire computer.

Comment: Did you come across any solution for this problem ?